# Azure websites .json extension handler mapping

Tags: azure, web, mapping

I have a website setup in the portal on Windows Azure but it will not serve files ending in .json as I guess there is no associated handler for the file type. This also happens with other text type files.

I simply want to server it as a text file with no processing, what is the handler mapping that I need to enter in the configuration page?

I need the extentsion (I presume *.json) and the script processor path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do that without any management portal GUI interaction.
All you have to do is to add the following to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/plain" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

If you already do have the "system.webServer" section just add it to this section.

Comment: How can this be done in the portal? I have a static html/js site consuming a client's api that are in another server. But they want to serve a static json file from our website.